# Slice vs Stride while reversing string

Tags: python

Normally to reverse a list one should do the following:

```
>>>>l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>>l[::-1]  
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

But isn't the exact syntax like this:

```
list[<start>:<end>:<stop>]
```

and if I don't give an optional parameter the defaults are as follows(Correct me if I am wrong:

```
<start> = 0(Beginning of list)
<end>   = 5(Length of list)
<step>  = 1
```

So if I give the optional parameters, it should in effect produce the same result:

```
>>>>l[0:5:-1]
>>>>[]
```

But instead I get an empty list(and I know why this happening), but what are the default values being taken by python in the 1st case?It should take 0 and 5 as default and produce nothing, or is **[::-1]** different from **list[start:end:stop]**

Comment: pretty sure what you mean is `list[start:stop:step]` as they call it in the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#slice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`l[::-1]` is equivalent to `l[slice(None,None,-1)]`, where [`slice([start], stop[, step])`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#slice) returns a [slice](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-slice) object. 
Consider the following:

```
>>> slice(None,None,-1).indices(5)
(4, -1, -1)
>>> slice(None,None,1).indices(5)
(0, 5, 1)
```

This is the exact behaviour you see when using the extended indexing syntax to access your list, i.e `l[start:stop:step]`.

```
>>> l[::-1]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> l[slice(None,None,-1)]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

---

> ... but what are the default values being taken by python in the 1st case?

The values for start/stop (if not provided) is based on the *number if indices* (length of list) as well as the value of `step`. Specifically, see the CPython [source for the slice object](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7d252dbfbee3/Objects/sliceobject.c#l161) (`Objects/sliceobject.c`)

```c
if (r->start == Py_None) {
    *start = *step < 0 ? length-1 : 0;
} else {
    /* .... */
}

if (r->stop == Py_None) {
    *stop = *step < 0 ? -1 : length;
} else {
    /* .... */
}
```

Comment: So python does in fact depend on the value of step while assigning default values?

Comment: Yes, it looks at the step as well as the length of the list.

Comment: @KartikAnand See updates for details on how the default values are calculated.

Comment: Thank you, this is in fact the best answer one could ask for regarding this question, I mean you uncovered basically what is happening inside.

Answer (score 2):

If your step is negative than your start at the end of the list .. you can do that using negative indexes.

Try:

```
l[-1:-6:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Start and stop are reversed if you're walking through the list backwards, try this:

```
l[5:0:-1]
```

Interestingly, it only slices 4 of the 5 elements (since "end" is supposed to be one past the end), and this doesn't work:

```
l[5:-1:-1]
```

This does what you're wanting though:

```
l[5::-1]
```

Comment: So actually python is playing with my arguments right? Shouldn't default values be "DEFAULT" and not change because of your arguments? :)

Comment: They are not really default values though, they are more inferred from the context.

Comment: @Brendan Long l[5:-1:-1] doesn't work for the same reason l[0:5:-1] doesn't work.It starts with 5 it subtracts one and it gets an index of "4".But since index "4" = index "-1" and it shouldn't include index "-1", it doesn't work.